How to discretize the Navier Stokes diffusive term on a quadtree mesh with staggered gird?
I'm currently trying to build a CFD code using the quadtree data structure. Everything is pretty much sorted out except for the diffusive term in the momentum equation.
I have looked for so many articles with the quadtree implemented but they all either use collocated grids or they don't talk about the viscous term. I don't know if it's because it's a stupid thing to use staggered grids for the quadtree or simply because most researchers just don't care about the viscous term enough to talk about it.
And so I don't know how I can discretize my diffusive term on the quadtree where I store velocities on the faces. Any ideas or articles that can help me learn about it would be great.
